# Python: Initialize a variable into if

Tags: python

Is there a way to do this in python?:

```
def exist(path_image):
    if path.isfile(path_image):
       return path_image
    else:
       return False

path_image = '/home/user/image.jpg'
if (image = exist(path_image)):
   print(image)
```

Other languages like PHP and Javascript, I can initialize a variable inside 'IF'

Thanks

Comment: you can't do this. Python was constructed to avoid this.

Comment: you could make it a side effect of a function call.  tho, it's not good idea.

Comment: No, Python *on purpose* makes assignment not an expression. A PEP was created proposing this, and it was never accepted: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0379/

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot do this in Python. A simple alternative would be:

```
image = exist('/home/user/image.jpg')
if (image):
   print(image)
```